# Regex does not contain string without using?

Tags: regex

I am trying to put together a piece of regex  to match lines that doesn't contain a certain string. So far I have the following:

```
/^((?!abc).)*$/igm
```

The issue I have is that the system I am trying to use doesn't support regex fully and so I am not able to use the `?!` notation.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: which lang/tool you're running?

Comment: Not sure on the language.  It's a web mail client which allows regex to be used in the rules.

Comment: Regex rules are almost the same for every language.

Comment: What are you using that piece of regex for??...Any common task to accomplish??..Because regex for daily tasks are available on the internet.

Comment: Its on a mail filter.  The regex is fine, it works on testing apps, but just doesn't work on the 3rd party client I'm trying to use it on

Comment: If the regex engine supports it: use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation you are trying to use is a **negative lookahead** assertion, and there are certain programming languages that don't support **lookaround** in regex, so if you are using one of those languages try to find an alternative library that support them .

If you can't enable support for **lookaround** assertions you simply can't negate the part of regex.

Comment: The system is 3rd party and I have no control over it.

Comment: So, I'm afraid you can't do what you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is possible, but in a very clumsy way.
Even something as simple as `abc` already results in a fairly obscure pattern:

```
^([^a]|a+[^ab]|a+b[ab]*[^abc])*[ab]*$
```

Fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/xH8dE9/3

Explanation:

```
^                    start of string
(
[^a]                 not 'a'
|
a+[^ab]              'a' but not 'ab'
|
a+b[ab]*[^abc]       'ab' but not 'abc'
)*
[ab]*$               left-overs at the end of the string
```

For longer words the pattern grows quadratically. Becomes particularly complicated for words with the first letter appearing more than once, e.g. `adam`. It would look something like this (untested):

```
^([^a]|a+[^ad]|a*(ad)+([^ad]|a[^adm]))*[ad]*$
```

You may want to use a tool to generate such patterns, rather than write them yourself.